# Getting objects in a Guice object graph

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to make a facade for a library I'm giving out. In my facade I use Guice to contruct the object graph. Deep in the object graph is a Proxy object, that has getURL/setURL methods.
In my facade, how do I get the Proxy instance used to create my root object? I want my facade to have url getter and setter.

I tried something like this:

```
public class SomeThingFacade() {

    private final SomeThing thing;
    private final HTTPProxy proxy;

    public SomeThingFacade() {
        MyModule module = new MyModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);

        // this is the main class I'm making a facade for
        this.thing = injector.getInstance(SomeThing.class);

        // deep in the "thing" object graph is a Proxy implementation
        this.proxy = injector.getInstance(HTTPProxy.class);
    }


    public void setURL(URL url) {
        this.proxy.setURL(url);
    }
}
```

but the injector.getInstance created a new instance.

Binding in MyModule:

```
bind(Proxy.class).to(HTTPProxy.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

I had previously hardcoded the object graph in the facade constructor, but it got unwieldly with 30 objects.

Basically, I need to configure an instance deep in the object graph after creation, but I'm not sure how I get a hold of that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally looks like a good serious question. However, I can't figure out what's being asked exactly.

My answer, looking at the code and ignoring the fascaded object graph talk (so let me know if I misunderstood you completely), is:
If `thing`'s `SomeThing` depends somewhere on a `deep internal proxy`, the module should configure it to be bound to `HTTPProxy` for thing. The second `getInstance` does not affect the first. The only way you could somehow be doing something that makes `proxy` affect `thing` is if HTTPProxy were bound `in(Singleton.class)`, then by calling methods on proxy that affect the members and behavior of `HTTPProxy` which would also be the same instance deep inside `thing` you might be doing what you're looking for. I don't see why you'd want to do it this way though. Consider instead writing a provider that configures `HTTPProxy` and/or making a special module just for the facade's use.

Comment: Basically, I need to configure an instance deep in the object graph after creation, but I'm not sure how I get a hold of that instance.

Comment: I think I hinted that you don't really get a hold of it, unless it happens to be a singleton. With injection you must configure the object before it's injected. In which case your module should define a providing method for the object http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods, or a provider http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings. Possibly with an instance specific annotation http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations. So if your facade needs a new config for proxy, define a specific module for the facade that does that.